# display in textView basic operation result android

Tags: android, textview

i have to show some operations in Android,,,

but Im having some noob problem,

```
public void calculateButtonPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.result);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Log.d("myTag",  "result biatch");

                String text=et.getText().toString();

                //toast msg
                //Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                // msg.show();

                //set Text
                tv.setText(text);

                //result_tv.setText("copao");

                int total = 1+2+3;

                result_tv.setText(total);

            }

        });

    }
```

so the app crashes , as im not using the variable correctly??

If I print the `result_tv.setText("copao");` it works fine

but on my basic operation the app crashes,

```
int total = 1+2+3;

result_tv.setText(total);
```

so what Im I missing?

thanks!

Comment: `result_tv.setText(String.parse(total));`

Comment: `String.parse` is not a valid statement in java.

Comment: result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total)); method is not applicable to set integer value, convert that into String object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is assuming your **total** value as a *string resource Id* which might not be available in the `R` class as a valid resource Id, causing the app to crash.

Change:

```
result_tv.setText(total);
```

To:

```
result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total));
//OR
result_tv.setText(total + ""); //to parse it as string
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
  result_tv.setText(total+""); or result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```